# Use Flex library APIs in HTML view

Tags: html, apache-flex

I have a set of Flex proprietary libraries (ActionScript APIs in SWCs), and I am wondering if it is possible to **build a UI completely in HTML using these APIs** for functionality, rather than a Flex based UI/view. If yes, what would be the approach (or some examples)?

One reason to do so is to re-use the existing Flex (domain layer) APIs (for the short term) rather than re-writing them in say, JavaScript.

Comment: Wait, what? Everything you just said makes no sense.  You want to use Flex components in html?  And which API are you talking about?  Are you just talking developer lingo without knowing what any of these acronyms mean?

Comment: I do understand those acronyms clearly. In short, yes what I am talking about is using Flex components (already existing in-house APIs) in HTML. May be an impossible ask (a polite 'makes no sense'), and I just wanted to make sure that is indeed IMPOSSIBLE! (or is there a work-around?)

Answer (score 0):

No HTML Renderers (AKA Browsers) that I'm aware of support ActionScript.  You will need a JavaScript/HTML port of your ActionScript code in order to use it in an HTML/JavaScript Web app.  For many things I expect this to be extremely difficult.

Answer (score 0):

http://ui.ajax.org offers a JavaScript framework that's very very close to Flex in terms of the components. It even uses an XML based layout framework like MXML called AML.

It also does bindings almost the same way as Flex with the `{}` markup, see: http://ui.ajax.org/#demos/features.smartbindings . I think that's about as close as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to use AS libraries in HTML/JS is to build SWF which exposes API of these libraries to JS through ExternalInterface.

You can use [JSInterface](http://code.google.com/p/jsinterface/) library, which is more convenient than raw ExternalInterface. Create JS object and map its properties into library API methods. Something like this (AS code):

```
var inited:Boolean = false;

try
{
    JSInterface.initialize( this );
    inited = true;
} catch( e:Error )
{
    trace( "ERROR cannot initialize JSInterface: " + e.message );
}

if( inited )
{
    var apiObject:JSDynamic = new JSDynamic( "Object" );
    apiObject.apiFunc1 = library.func1;
    apiObject.apiFunc2 = library.func2;
    // etc

    JSInterface.window.yourAPIName = apiObject;
}
```

Thereafter you'll be able to access library functions within JS code by calling `yourAPIName.apiFunc1()`, `yourAPIName.apiFunc2()` and so on.

Would it be acceptable or not strongly depends on the nature of your libraries. In case of UI libraries, I'm sure that it is impossible to use them without rewriting the code in JS.